# Calculating Posterior Distribution

Tags: self-study, bayesian, posterior

I am in an intro to statistics course and my instructor gave a problem stated exactly as follows:

> A box contains 50 items.
>   A sample contains 10 defective and 20 non-defective.
>   Calculate the posterior distribution of the count of defective items in the box with and without replacement.

I feel as if there are missing criteria from his question.  Is there enough information given to answer it?

Comment: There can be no posterior without a prior: ask your instructor what prior distribution to assume.  If he says that only one is reasonable or possible, then he's probably a century or more old, so you should treat him gently.

Comment: Haha see that's what I was thinking as well. I was just going to assume that the prior probability is 50% for choosing a defective item.

Comment: That is a somewhat informative prior--but it's sufficiently general in nature that you would be justified doing the exercise with that assumption, provided you make it clear that you know it's a (somewhat) arbitrary assumption you have adopted to order to get a solution. (Some people might argue that it's an "uninformative" prior, but in applications there's no such thing. Imagine, for instance, this box represents output of a manufacturing process and the sample is part of a quality control procedure. The manufacturer might be alarmed at the assumption that half their products are defective!)

Comment: Good point. What if we treat the sample of 10 defective and 20 non-defective as the prior? And based on that sample, find the posterior distribution of number of defective items in the box.

Comment: Some people do such a thing but I expect the instructor didn't have that (using the data twice) in mind here.

Comment: @whuber "alarmed" is kind of an understatement - plant managers have been fired for defect rates order of magnitudes smaller than that, and our industrial segment is surely not the one with the strictest requirements :)